# what's the meaning of square root of R-squared?

Tags: regression, correlation

In my daily work, I do a lot of least square regression using R or scipy

```
y ~ \beta * X
```

y is around the size of 10000

X is around the dimension of 100 (100 factors)

I always take the square root of $R^2$ as a measure of correlation. Say, I see a $R^2$ of 0.36, I will assume a 60% correlation between $y$ and $\hat{y}$.

Today, during an interview, the interviewer said this is wrong. I am quite confused at this point. I definitely remember  the square root of R2 means something about correlation.

Can someone clarify this for me here?

Comment: regression? multiple or simple?

Comment: It's sample correlation coefficient between prediction and response

Comment: Your edit isn't good enough. There're many possible regressions for your equation. Tell us exactly about your regression model. What method did you fit your model? Least-squares?

Comment: @StudentT No it's not only for simple linear, please check it

Comment: I think it would have been clearer if you had said "a correlation of .6" rather  than "a 60% correlation."

Answer (score 8):

You are correct, 007. For multiple linear regression, the square root of $R^2$ is the correlation coefficent between the vectors of observed and predicted values of the response.

[Here is Wikipedia on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_correlation)

and here is some R code to check in an example:

```
set.seed(100)

# simulate some data
X <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(1000), x2=rnorm(1000))
X$y <- X$x1 + X$x2 + rnorm(1000)

# fit model
model <- lm(y~., data=X)

# find R^2
summary(model)

# make predictions
yhat <- predict(model,X)

# calculate correlation between y and yhat and square it
cor(yhat, X$y)^2 # equal to R^2 in summary(model)
```

Comment: Exactly, we have to write a petition to fire the interviewer. Just to add up, for simple linear it is also correlation between explanatory and dependent.

Comment: You do need to require that the intercept is in the model. When there is no intercept, $R^2$ is kind of an elusive animal.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit why interception is important here?

Answer (score 0):

The correlation coefficient is not a percentage - it can be negative. It is a measure of linear dependence between X and Y.

Comment: This is a special case, though: the correlation coefficient between the response and its OLS prediction (assuming an intercept term is included) cannot be negative.